# Import specific data from excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have a couple of excel files, all in a specific format. I need to get data from each of them and show all of it, at the same time on my program.

The problem is, my data is in specific cells.

- My first data is in cell C2
- Second data is near bottom of file. Columns still the same at every file but the rows differentiate. So I have to write a loop to find that row. Maybe if (row-1==" ") like a code may written in a for loop.

Here is my so far code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    String[] genel = new String [1000];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    }

    private void btnGozat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray());
        }

        textBox1.Text =fbd.SelectedPath;

        String[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        genel = allfiles;
    }

    private void btnAnaliz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] checkedFiles = new String[checkedListBox1.Items.Count];

        int count;
        int checkF = 0;

        for (count = 0; count < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(count))
            {
                checkedFiles[checkF] = genel[count];
                checkF++;
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a macro? A C# application? and what exactly have you done so far?

Comment: This is a C# application. So far, opened the folder contains the files using FolderBrowserDialog, showed files in folder in a checkedlistbox, got the selected files' paths.

Comment: What library are you using to communicate with excel? [Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx)?  And it may be helpful to post what code you have so far

Comment: Heya - code-formatting in comments is truly awful... Could you possibly edit your question and add the code there so we can all read it easily? Many thanks!

Comment: I added the code. I'm new at this site's format, sorry. @chancea

Comment: Now that the code is in the question, please delete the copy in comments.  Mouse over your comments and an X icon should appear on the last line of each to the right of how long ago they were posted.

Comment: what is the question here??

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I hope it helps:

```
ExcelReader reader = new ExcelReader();
reader.ConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", dataSource);

DataSet testData = reader.ConvertToDataSet(workSheet);
```

You have a different class `ExcelReader` and method `ConvertToDataSet`.

```
public ExcelReader(string connectionString)
{
    _connectionString = connectionString;
}

public DataSet ConvertToDataSet(string workSheetName)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + workSheetName + "$]", ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    adapter.Fill(ds, "Standard");

    return ds;
}
```

After that you have the Excel file in a `DataSet` and you can manipulate the data.

You also need one connection string property!

Comment: @user3818470 if the question helped you, you can mark it as correct !